# TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null | Vue Utils - Jest Framework | Can't able to run test case for this

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, testcase

I am using Vue utils jest framework for cover my vue.js. while run its shown error like this. Please refer screen shot. [image]

my vue code is below

```
  <div id="tile" class="tile" data-scale="2.4" @mouseover="cursorEnters" @mouseout="cursorLeaves" @mousemove="cursorMove($event)" :data-image="imageUrl"
  >
```

my js code is below

```
mounted() {
   this.initializationImageZoom();
},    
initializationImageZoom() {
  const tile = document.querySelector('#tile');
  tile.innerHTML += '<div id="photo" class="photo"></div>';
  tile.children[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.imageUrl + ')';
},
```

Below my test case

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

const imageUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ETsekJKsr3M/maxresdefault.jpg";

let wrapper;
const ImageZoom = require('./ImageZoom.vue').default;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallowMount(ImageZoom, {
    propsData: {
      imageUrl,
    }
  });
});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
});

describe('NoRecords.vue', () => {
  it('should have props (imageUrl) type as Object', () => {
    expect(typeof wrapper.vm.imageUrl).toBe('string');
 });
});
```

While rendering the vue component by test case. its shown error like that (Refer screen shot)

Comment: @tony19 I have updated the question and my vue code. Please refer that and help me

Comment: can you add test case you are writing for this function ?

Comment: @NipunJain I have updated my test case. If i started to render this error occured.(Refer screen shot)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

const imageUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ETsekJKsr3M/maxresdefault.jpg";

// Creating #tile div

let tile = document.createElement('div')
tile.setAttribute("id", "tile")
let children = document.createElement('div')
tile.appendChild(children)
document.body.appendChild(tile)

let wrapper;
const ImageZoom = require('./ImageZoom.vue').default;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallowMount(ImageZoom, {
    propsData: {
      imageUrl,
    }
  });
});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
});

describe('NoRecords.vue', () => {
  it('should have props (imageUrl) type as Object', () => {
    expect(typeof wrapper.vm.imageUrl).toBe('string');
 });
});
```

I just create a div element in the body so that jest dont throw an error.

Comment: It's worked for me. But its not a proper way. Need to solve exact scenario. some what i got idea from your side. any way thank you